Desktop icon and folder is showing but not files. How to get the files back?
I'm facing an issue. My desktop and folders are showing but my all files are missing. I checked inside the trash it is not there..I haven't deleted the files. How do I get the files back?

Your details are contradictory; you've not told us what Ubuntu product you're using (Server? Desktop?) though do mention desktop; but also state your question is about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and also Ubuntu 22.04 LTS which is a different release. If you've deleted files, they may not appear in the trash as they only appear in trash if deleted in specific ways (some methods bypass trash). You've provided no context for us to help with, and contradictory release details, are you using Ubuntu? Getting files back is by restoring from backups, but you've not given details of your backup strategy.
